# MySQL Syntax error in cursor loop

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, cursor, syntax-error

I am trying to run a cursor loop in a stored procedure using this script:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE migrateMStruct()
BEGIN
DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE msId BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED;
DECLARE luId INT(11);

DECLARE msCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT id, live_unit_id FROM mounting_structures
    WHERE live_unit_id IS NOT NULL;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = TRUE;

OPEN msCursor;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH msCursor INTO msId, luId;
    IF finished THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    UPDATE live_units SET mountingStructureId = msId WHERE live_units.id = luId;
END LOOP;

CLOSE msCursor;
END;
```

I wrote this script based on the MySQL documentation, but when executing the script I'm receiving the error:

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' 
at line 19
```

Line 19 is just the `END IF;` statement. Obviously not the most helpful error in the world, but based on MySQL's documentation, the syntax looks to be correct.

Comment: Why not use a simple `UPDATE live_units INNER JOIN mounting_structures ON live_units.id = mounting_structures.live_unit_id SET live_units.mountingStructureId = mounting_structures.id WHERE mounting_structures.live_unit_id IS NOT NULL` ??   then you don't need to use a CURSOR.

Comment: That does seem to get the job done, thanks. My coworker seemed to think I'd need to use a cursor. I'm still curious what's wrong with my syntax, but at least that does what I need.

Comment: Use the `delimiter` command, see [23.1 Defining Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

Comment: I suspect your suggestion would also fix the problem @wchiquito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error, you must to change the delimiter character temporary to prevent execution when the SQL interpreter found a semicolon `;`

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE migrateMStruct()
BEGIN

  /*your procedure body*/

END$$

DELIMITER ;  /*back to previous delimiter*
```